# Could anyone please explain the sentence

Tags: verbs

I saw the sentence in a dictionary.I couldn't understand what he did, even though I understood what the verb meant which was to be unable to move.

> He jammed the window open with a piece of wood.

Thank you

Comment: He put a piece of wood in such a position that the window could not move back into a closed position.

Comment: If a sliding window will not stay up/open by itself, you can jam it open by many things, including a piece of wood, or some random object, such as one's grammar book.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sentence taken from [Cambridge Advanced Learner's Dictionary](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=PDHCFSRmjSMC&pg=PA770&dq=%22He%20jammed%20the%20window%20open%20with%20a%20piece%20of%20wood%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=VywNVaWxB4O6uATpmoHgBw&ved=0CCEQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=%22He%20jammed%20the%20window%20open%20with%20a%20piece%20of%20wood%22&f=false).

As a verb, 'jam' means '[to be or make something unable to move](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/jam)' or '[to make or become stuck or locked'.](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/JAM)

Therefore, here a piece of wood makes that open window locked. Which means that now that open window is unable to close.

Hope this would help.

Answer (score 2):

The window was open. He used a piece of wood to make the window unable to move to closed. So the window would stay open.

Answer (score 1):

In the context of a window being "jammed", I think the sentence suggests that the piece of wood was forced into the window along the track of a double hung window (which does not have a direct relation to the verb "jam" that I am aware).  Putting a book or other object into a window to keep it open would typically be phrased "propping open the window".  Jamming infers some force.